# Calculating a preceding Wednesday from a static date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to provide a date for the prior Wednesday. The following formula works for Monday:

```
=A2-CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A2,2),7,1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

When I adjust for a Tuesday date (switching the serial number to 3), everything EXCEPT Mondays work. Adjusting for Wednesday doesn't work at all when I substitute the 2 with 4.

Comment: you need to change the numbers in the choose: =A2-CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A2,2),5,6,7,1,2,3,4)

Comment: or use `13`: `=A2-CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A2,13),7,1,2,3,4,5,6)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY($A5)>=$B$2,$A5-(WEEKDAY($A5)-$B$2),$A5-WEEKDAY($A5)-7+$B$2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this one:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `K4`:

  `=I4-MOD(WEEKDAY(I4)+2,7)-1`
- Applied cell format is, `dddd dd mmm yy`.

**How it works:**

- MOD(,,,, 7) returns value from 0 to 6.
- MOD(,,,)-1 subtracts value, 1 to 7 as days for the given Date.
- +2 in this formula is editable, to get different weekdays.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date of any preceding ***day_of_week*** with a formula like:

```
=A2-WEEKDAY(A2-DOW)
```

Where `DOW` = the number returned by the `WEEKDAY` function for that date.

eg:  Sunday = 1; Monday = 2; etc.

So, for previous Wednesday, `DOW=4`
[image]